# How many ways can I rearrange 4 numbers between zero&ten so that the digits are decreasing?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have this question
[image]

and this answer

[image]

My question is regarding part (b) and (c).

for part (b) I understand that there are 10 digits to choose from and we need to choose 4 but how does 10C4 guarantee that they will be in decreasing order? I don't understand the logic behind using the choose function entirely?

for part (c) I understand they have chosen 4C2 because there are 4 slots, we chose 2 even digits(or odd) and the other's fall into place. But what is meant by "there are 625 ways of choosing an even, even, odd, odd combination" and why are we multiplying by this number? How did they even get 625?

Thanks!

Comment: $\binom{10}{4}$ denotes the number of size-four subsets of the size-ten set $\{0,1,2,\dots,9\}$.  The important observation here is that there is a *direct bijection* between size four subsets of $\{0,1,2,\dots,9\}$ and four-digit numbers where the digits are in decreasing order, namely given some size four subset, for example $\{1,4,5,7\}$ just write the numbers in decreasing order and call it one number, in this case $7541$.  Note that there is only one way to do this for any subset, that no two subsets give the same result, and that every four-digit number comes from exactly one subset.

Comment: For part $(c)$, once we know whether we are looking at even-odd-odd-even  or at odd-even-odd-even, or whatever, from left to right decide what the number occupying that slot is.  There are five choices each time, giving $5\cdot 5\cdot 5\cdot 5=625$ total options for how to assign the numbers themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $b)$: Every $4$ different numbers give a unique number such that its digits are in increasing order, hence you need to count the number of such quadruplets

For $c)$: You have $5$ choices for an even digit and $5$ for an odd - hence there are $5^4=625$ combinations of the form even, even, odd, odd